# How to design my program properly?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I've seen in many samples that a programmer uses only a thin and narrow picture or some small pictures to design their program with expanding those pictures or sometimes they put many icons in a picture and later use them.

I was wondering how do they do it and for example how to use small pictures as my form background.

Sorry for my bad English by the way.

Comment: Which technology? Winforms or WPF? Please add appropriate tags. Your question is about UI design, please remove the design tag.

Comment: Do you mean "how to tile a smaller picture all over my form's background"?

Comment: Yes that's what I meant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many developers put multiple images inside one single image. You can [draw a portion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142040%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of an image using the [graphics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) object.

Imagine one have an image containing 10 images of size 16x16 (px).

```
Dim image As New Bitmap((10 * 16), 16)
```

Now, if one is to draw the third image as your background image you do it like this:

```
Public Class MyForm
    Inherits Form

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer Or ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw Or ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, True)
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs)

        'The source image.
        Dim image As Bitmap = My.Resources.myimage

        'The number of the image to be drawn. (1 - 10)
        Dim nr As Integer = 3

        'The x axis of the image portion.
        Dim x As Integer = (16 * (nr - 1))

        'Destination rectangle. (MyForm)
        Dim destinationRect As New Rectangle(0, 0, Me.Width, Me.Height)

        'Source rectangle. The portion of the image to be drawn.
        Dim imagePortionRect As New Rectangle(x, 0, 16, 16)

        'Draw image.
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(image, destinationRect, imagePortionRect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel)

        MyBase.OnPaint(e)

    End Sub

End Class
```